How to distribute LGPL2.1 dependency shared lib with a python package?
I am working on python bindings for a C library, which uses LGPL2.1.
My Python bindings for the library link dynamically against it. For the python bindings to work when installed I need to ship them with the LGPL2.1 library via pip.
My questions are as:

Can I license my work (the Python package itself) under a different license? (As far as I understand the answer to this is yes, since I am linking dynamically against the lib)
Do I need to include the LGPL2.1 license inside the Python package? Are there any examples I can look at that do this?
Do I need to include anything else in the package? For example the source code for the LGPL2.1 lib.
Do I need to mention that the python package uses this library underneath?

